# jQuery get value Input Text

Tags: php, jquery, input

Here is my HTML code :

```
<input type="text" name="Estimation1" id="Val1" maxlength="3" disabled=true/>
<input type="text" name="Estimation2" id="Val2" maxlength="3" disabled=true/>
<input type="text" name="Estimation3" id="Val3" maxlength="3" disabled=true/>
<input type="text" name="Estimation4" id="Val4" maxlength="3" disabled=true/>
```

And My jQuery :

```
function CalculAuto()
{

    // get the values from this row:
    var val1 = $('#Val1').val();
    var val2 = $('#Val2').val();
    var val3 = $('#Val3').val();
    if (val1=="") val1=0;
    if (val2=="") val2=0;
    if (val3=="") val3=0;
    var total = 100 - ((val1 * 1) + (val2 * 1) +  (val3 * 1));
    // set total for the row
    $('#Val4').attr('value', total);
}
```

My problem is : when I send my form, `$_POST['Estimation4']` is not recognized.
I don't understand why ??

Comment: it is empty or not initialized ?

Comment: Show your `ajax` code or the code through which you send your values.

Comment: what is result of var_dump($_POST); ?

Comment: is this really disabled? of course it undefined since it won't reach `$_POST`, change to `<input type="text" name="Estimation4" id="Val4" maxlength="3" readonly />` instaed

Comment: Not initialized==> "Notice: Undefined index: Estimation4 in..."

Comment: On an unrelated topic: Why are you multiplying the numbers with `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important** You need to remove `disabled` attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="Estimation4" id="Val4" maxlength="3"/>
```

Use, `.val()` to set value. like

```
$('#Val4').val(total);
```

Instead of

```
$('#Val4').attr('value', total);
```

`.val()` function gives you string. Hence you need to convert string value into appropriate one.

1. Use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for  **floating point number**. operation
2. Use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for operation on **integers**.

*Complete Code*

```
function CalculAuto()
{

    // get the values from this row:
    var val1 = $('#Val1').val();
    var val2 = $('#Val2').val();
    var val3 = $('#Val3').val();

    val1 = val1=="" ? 0 : parseFloat(val1);
    val2 = val2=="" ? 0 : parseFloat(val2);
    val3 = val3=="" ? 0 : parseFloat(val3);

    var total = 100 - ((val1 * 1) + (val2 * 1) +  (val3 * 1));
    // set total for the row
    $('#Val4').val(total);
}
```

Comment: I've tested .Val() and it has the same effect that .Attr('value', 'string')

Comment: @user3710123, No they don't have same effect. Also did you removed `disabled` attribute.

Comment: But how can I do to block this field?

Comment: And I have changed CalculAuto() with parseInt() function. Thx!

Comment: @user3710123, You can use `readonly` attribute. You can programmatically change its value.